# Rotate icon and toggle content onclick at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation, toggle

I'm trying to rotate a icon when i click on a link next to the icon.
The idea is when I click on the link, the icon rotate and the content slide down. I have manage to make the content slide down but I can't get the icon to rotate in the same script.

This is the script:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $(".change_delivery_address").click(function(){
$(".spm").slideToggle();
  });  
});
```

This is de html:

```
<div class="change_delivery_address"><h6>Choose another delivery address<img src="images/layout-            img/menu-icons/arrow_carrot-right.png"></h6>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.change_delivery_address h6{
cursor: pointer;
color: #3274f4;
margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;

}

.change_delivery_address h6:active{
background: none;
}

.spm {

display: none;
}
```

Hope you someone can help me out with this thanks.

Comment: The script you have up there currently only performs a slidetoggle. Can you include the full script that you are using which is causing problems?

Comment: I don't know how to implement the rotation in my code thats why I just post the slide toggle code

Comment: @TheHamstring This is what I have now:<script>
var rotated = false;
$(".change_delivery_address").click(function(){
    $(".spm").slideToggle();
    if(rotated) {
        rotateAngle = -90;
    }
    else {
        rotateAngle = 90;
    }
    $("#icon").toggleClass("rotate");
});
</script>


The HTML:

<div class="change_delivery_address">
  <img id="icon" src="images/layout-img/menu-icons/arrow_carrot-right.png">
  <h6>Choose another delivery address</h6></div>

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your problem is that you haven't included any rotation in your `click` function.

include `JQueryRotate`, a small library that allows rotation, by adding

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js">
```

and then your script should look like this. Because I'm assuming that you want it to rotate and then rotate back, I'm adding a boolean to check which way it's rotated and act accordingly because there's no `rotateToggle`:

```
var rotated = false;
$(".change_delivery_address").click(function(){
    $(".spm").slideToggle();
    if(rotated) {
        rotateAngle = -90;
    }
    else {
        rotateAngle = 90;
    }  
    $("img[src='images/layout-img/menu-icons/arrow_carrot-right.png']").rotate(rotateAngle)
});
```

Comment: the problem that i'm heaving with your code is that is not showing the icon. is there a other way to show image through query?

Comment: You could add `id="icon"` to your `img` and then find it with `$("#icon")`

Comment: so that'd be `<img id="icon" src="images/layout-img/menu-icons/arrow_carrot-right.png">`

Comment: is that what you're asking for?

Comment: This is what I have now: <script>
var rotated = false;
$(".change_delivery_address").click(function(){
    $(".spm").slideToggle();
    if(rotated) {
        rotateAngle = -90;
    }
    else {
        rotateAngle = 90;
    }
    $("#icon").toggleClass("rotate");
});
</script>

Comment: Oh and this is the html:    

<div class="change_delivery_address">
  <img id="icon" src="images/layout-img/menu-icons/arrow_carrot-right.png">
  <h6>Choose another delivery address</h6></div>

Comment: and what exactly is not working about it? Sorry I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the additional jQuery library you can also apply a CSS class to the image to rotate the image as well. You would use the transform property described here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp. Additionally you can also apply a transition through CSS as well to animate the icon turning. The benefit here is no additional plugins but this is supported only in HTML5 supporting browsers, so if you will run into problems in IE8.

I don't know what will work best for you but I wanted to throw out an additional option.